# Organizing disk file for very fast access

Tags: data-structures, disk

I am developing key value database similar to Apache Cassandra and LevelDB.

It utilize `LSM trees` (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-structured_merge-tree)

Keys are strings and I am using C++.

Currently data is stored on disk in several IMMUTABLE "sstables", each with two files.

- data file - "flat" file - record after record, sorted by key, without any disk block alignment.
- index file - it contains number of records and array of 8 byte numbers (uint64_t) offcets to each record. You can position (seek) and find offset to any record from data file.

I have mmap-ed these two files in memory.

If I program need to locate a record it do binary search. However this means the program do lots of disk seeks. I did some optimizations, for example i actually do jump search and sequentially read last 40-50 records. But on file with 1 billion keys, it still do 20-25 seeks (instead of 30).

This all works pretty fast - 4-5 seconds for 1 billion keys without virtual memory cache (e.g. first ever request) and way under 1 second with virtual memory cache.

However I am thinking of building some additional data structure on the disk that can speed up the lookup more. I thought to use "level ordered array", e.g. instead of:

1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7

to be

4, 2, 6, 1, 3, 5, 7

In this case, most used keys will be at the beginning of the file, but I am not 100% sure it will help that much.

second though is to do something like B Tree or B+Tree, but creation seems very complex with lot of disk syncs - or at least this is how I see it.

Apache Cassandra is using key samples - it have every 1024th key in memory - I do not want to go this way, because of memory consumption. However, if I have them on disk in "flat" file, it still needs lots of seeks to find the "sample" key.

Is there any alternative I am missing?